# Website wont resolve, Domain/website name different

Tags: domain-name-system

my domain is AD.EXAMPLE.COM - Inhouse Server

Website is WWW.EXAMPLE.COM -on Godaddy

Server 2012 w/ DNS looking to itself and forwarders set to google DNS

When I try to browse to our website i get nothing, page cannot be displayed. I can ping anything and get back the Godaddy IP w/ response I can NSLOOKUP and get back example.com or www.example.com and the godaddy IP There is no redirect from www.to .example.com the www. stays on it.

This issue came out of nowhere, I believe the issue is in my DNS on server 12 but the fact is I never set it up special for this in the first place and it just broke at random.

Comment: If you get the correct IP its not the DNS. The problem is the Website itself. Maybe GoDaddy updated some packages and your website isn't compatible.

Comment: It resolves for any other location except from my domain computers

Comment: Oh I see. Well with the info you gave us we can't help you. We need some configuration at least.